# Matplotlib subplot title, figure title formatting

Tags: python, matplotlib

How would I go about formatting the below pie chart subplots so that there is more white-space between the fig title and subplot titles. Ideally the subplot titles would also be in closer vicinity to the actual pie chart itself.

I can't seem to find anything in the docs which might enable this, but I'm new to matplotlib.

[image: matplotlib figure]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame, Series

m = {"Men" :  {"Yes": 2, "No": 8}}
w = {"Women": {"Yes": 3, "No": 7}}
data = {**m, **w}
df = DataFrame(data)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, len(df.columns))
fig.suptitle("Would you prefer to work from home?", fontsize=18)
logging.debug("fig.axes: {}".format(fig.axes))

for i, ax in enumerate(fig.axes):
    col = df.ix[:, i]
    ax = fig.axes[i]
    pcnt_col = col / col.sum() * 100
    ax.set_title("{} (n={})".format(pcnt_col.name, col.sum()))
    ax.pie(pcnt_col.values, labels=pcnt_col.index,
                    autopct="%1.1f%%", startangle=90)
    ax.axis("equal")
    plt.legend(loc="lower right", title="Answer", fancybox=True,
               ncol=1, shadow=True)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `subplots_adjust` to separate the two

```
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.75)
```

---

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame, Series

m = {"Men" :  {"Yes": 2, "No": 8}}
w = {"Women": {"Yes": 3, "No": 7}}
data = {**m, **w}
df = DataFrame(data)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, len(df.columns))
fig.suptitle("Would you prefer to work from home?", fontsize=18)
logging.debug("fig.axes: {}".format(fig.axes))

for i, ax in enumerate(fig.axes):
    col = df.ix[:, i]
    ax = fig.axes[i]
    pcnt_col = col / col.sum() * 100
    ax.set_title("{} (n={})".format(pcnt_col.name, col.sum()))
    ax.pie(pcnt_col.values, labels=pcnt_col.index,
                    autopct="%1.1f%%", startangle=90)
    ax.axis("equal")
    plt.legend(loc="lower right", title="Answer", fancybox=True,
               ncol=1, shadow=True)
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.55)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: @SiHa milage may vary... legend wasn't in the same position on my screen as the OP with OP code.

Comment: OK, fair enough :)

Comment: I used keyword arg 'bbox_to_anchor=(1.2, -0.1)' in plt.legend to move the legend to the bottom right hand corner of the figure.